# connecting to mysql 8.x from pentaho data-integration(kettle)

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, mysql-8.0

I have table input and insert/update component on my transformation. when i put all parameters for mysql8 and click on test, it was successful and able to connect. But when i browse table I am getting following error

**Unable to retrieve database information because of an error

Error getting views from schema [null]
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('VIEW',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SCH' at line 1

- I have latest mysql8.x jar in lib directory

Answer (score 0):

this is not related with pentaho kettle, you have an error in your query

Comment: thank you. I haven't used any order statement on my query. it is just a select statement selecting few columns from a table in table input come

Comment: Are you sure that this query is correct? Did you try to execute it using any mysql client tool (MySqlworkbench for example) ?